# nav menu last child is getting hidden behind the first dropdown

Tags: html, jquery

having trouble getting the last child dropdown to show up in front or beside the first child dropdown menu. changed the z-index in different spots. Still nothing has changed. not sure how if my CSS or HTML or jquery needs fixing.

the link to the site is at the bottom of the page.

```
/*--.has-sub .sub-menu .sub-menu*/

#navCssMenu > ul > li:last-child{
box-shadow: none;
}

#navCSSMenu ul > li:last-child > ul{
z-index:9999;
position: absolute;
top: 13px;
right: 10px;
width: 4px;
height: 4px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
content: '';
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
```

/*END .has-sub .sub-menu .sub-menu--*/

site: https://www.cellregenwellness.com/home40731362

Comment: under the services dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this rule:

```css
ul.sub-menu {
  z-index: 60;
}
```

Alternatively you can use jQuery to fix problems with text not shown and menu overlap.

```js
$(".sub-menu ul").css("z-index", 60);
$(".sub-menu li a").css("padding-top", "5px");
$(".sub-menu li a").css("padding-bottom", "5px");
$(".sub-menu li").css("height", "fit-content");
```

Comment: Changed the z index but it's still hiding behind the first dropdown... there is a jquery code too.. I a had to add the last child pages.. not sure what isn't working

Comment: @superdidi411 I have edited my answer and added jQuery easy to test in console.

Comment: okay updated.. YES it was in the jquery. I was thinking so cause I'm new to jquery all the CSS updates weren't working. Thanks so much derloopkat!